# Convert array of points from Ink.StrokeCollection to Path Array freeDrawingBrush Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, c#, xml, fabricjs

I'm using the fabric.js in one project, right now I'm trying to convert a legacy xml array of point to the fabricjs objects.

The legacy project has a xml persistence saved to DB. In C# is a System.Windows.Ink.StrokeCollection using InkPresenter Control in Silverlight

This is the xml generated
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/20269820/18906832/153537a0-8561-11e6-91ca-6bbbec70d859.png

For fabric.js I tried to create similar prototype, then I have the following:

I check the path array object in fabricjs:
[Two objects in fabric js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa6XI.png)
Is there any way that I could convert that xml structure to the fabric path structure? I could just create a new one using fabric, but I need still to cater for the legacy, in that case I need to find out a way to convert that structure to fabric.

Thank you

For more details: github. com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/3295

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fabric.Path structure is a svg Path structure.
I see your structure was a simple array of points.

Imagining you have 4 points (p1, p2, p3, p4) in your drawing archive, the respective command would be:

`var pathCommand = "M p1.x p1.y L p2.x p2.y p3.x p3.y p4.x p4.y"`

Then you could do `new fabric.Path(pathCommand, options)` where options include stroke ( your color ) and strokeWidth ( your width ).

That would give you a polyline aspect object.

If you want to mimic the fabric freeDrawingMode with that points you have to check the pencilBrush code you can find here:

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.js.html#line7882

And that can convert an array of points in some quadratic smoother curve.

Comment: I think mimic the freeDrawingMode is the one I'm looking for. Is there any place were I can find how to use the convertPointsToSVGPath and add to the canvas? Because I need to load the path in the canvas with freeDrawingMode

Comment: did you solve then or need more insight on how to convert to freeDrawing data? i completely forgot about this.

Answer (score 3):

The created the solution based on the @AndreaBogazzi suggestion.

```
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
    isDrawingMode: true
});

if (canvas.freeDrawingBrush) {
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "#000000";
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 3;
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.shadowBlur = 0;
}
var pencil = new fabric.PencilBrush(canvas);
var points = [{x: 11, y: 12}, {x: 11, y: 11}, {x: 12, y: 11}];
// Convert Points to SVG Path
var res = pencil.convertPointsToSVGPath(points);
// Create the Path
var path = pencil.createPath(res.toString());
// Set the tickness and color
path.set({ strokeWidth: 3, stroke: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)" });
// Add to the Canvas
canvas.add(path);
```

To revert the path back to Array of Points:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < canvas.getObjects().length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < canvas.getObjects()[i].path.length; j++) {
        arr.push({
            x: canvas.getObjects()[i].path[j][1],
            y: canvas.getObjects()[i].path[j][2]
        });
    }
}
```